# What method do wireless routers use to break apart the received wave into different frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism

What method do wireless routers use to break apart the received wave into different frequencies ?

Does it have anything to do with Fourier Transformations ?

Comment: "Filters" is the word that springs to mind, specifically band-pass filters.

Comment: Well, i know how analog filters work , but when it comes to high frequencies, do analog filters still apply ?  i just assumed it all goes into the digital realm and math kicks in

Comment: I didn't mention "analogue".

Comment: @Andyaka no you didn't :) my mistake. any good reference to the the configurations of filters that does the work ? or maybe an IC that you can think of that fits this criteria ?

Comment: Well, you could start with the standard: http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal from the antenna is limited to the desired RF band(s) using SAW filters, so that strong non-ISM signals (e.g. DECT phones) can not upset the mixer.

Channel selection is typically performed as a classic heterodyne receiver using a PLL as clock source for the LO, and another SAW band-pass filter on the IF, or a simple low-pass filter in a zero-IF design.

The thousands of carriers used in OFDM are split digitally in the base band processor using FFT.

Comment: There's generally some sort of band pass filter for the 2.4 GHz ISM band as well, to protect the front end from strong out of band spurious. This would typically be a SAW filter.